# Routing using StateProvider gets redirected if parameter contains Slash '/'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs to create a page. Page url configured with stateproviders. URL contains a parameter. This parameter sometimes has slash '/' sign. When this slash sign occurs in parameter routing changes to default url.

I am creating website to host it in IIS. WCF services are used.

Please let me know how I can resolve this problem to accept slash in parameter and not to redirect.

Config looks like as follows -

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

$stateProvider
.state('Home', {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "Partials/Landing.html?",
})

  .state('Search', {
      url: "/search/:search",
      templateUrl: "Partials/Search.html?",
  })
```

When I call Search state with following parameter it redirects it to Home state

```
<a ui-sref=".Search({search:spam/closed})" class="list-group-item"/>
```

OR

```
$state.go("Search", {"search" : "spam/closed"});
```

Comment: you can use the `encodeURI() function`

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to separate several keywords as Searched value, I think you should try to find another character to separate them ("spam" and "closed") on the basis that the slash `/` is a reserved character in URL's as per [RFC1738](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt).

> Reserved:
>
> Many URL schemes reserve certain characters for a special meaning: their appearance in the scheme-specific part of the URL has a designated semantics. If the character corresponding to an octet is reserved in a scheme, the octet must be encoded.  The characters ";", "/", "?", ":", "@", "=" and "&" are the characters which may be reserved for special meaning within a scheme. No other characters may be reserved within a scheme.

Maybe you can use a something else and explode the string accordingly.

Alternatively if you know the maximum number of search variables you have, you can just declare more routes: `search/:search1/:search2` etc. It's not a very flexible solution, and angular doesn't do route wildcards

Answer (score 0):

In certain versions of UI-Router, you can do this by specifying the "any" type for your parameter. See this issue in [UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1119):

> I should add that somewhere between 0.2.13 and 0.2.15, ui-router broke querystring components with slashes. In 0.2.13 you could have a state like this:
>
> `url: "path?param1&param2"`
>
> In 0.2.15 that will no longer work if the parameter values have slashes in them: the encode/decode round trip will give back a different result than the original value, just like it was already broken for path components in 0.2.13.
>
> In 0.2.15 you will have to use the any type like this:
>
> `url: "path?{param1:any}&{param2:any}"`

Credit to GitHub user [drothlis](https://github.com/drothlis) for that.